# pjsua_media.c Unable to open sound device: No suitable sound capture device

Tags: iphone, ios, sip

I am writing code for a SIP application to make a SIP call. I'm getting the following error after running. Does anyone have the solution?

15:01:12.039  pjsua_media.c ..failed: No suitable sound capture device

Comment: is this a programming question or a "I can't use TabikPhone" usage question?

Comment: 15:01:10.879  pjsua_media.c pjsua_set_snd_dev(): attempting to open devices @16000 Hz
 15:01:10.879    ipodsound.c pjmedia_snd_stream_start.
 15:01:10.879    ipodsound.c pjmedia_snd_stream_start : play back starting...
 15:01:10.940    ipodsound.c pjmedia_snd_stream_start : play back started
 15:01:10.940    ipodsound.c pjmedia_snd_stream_start : capture starting...
 15:01:11.432    ipodsound.c Starting capture stream error -66681
 15:01:11.432    ipodsound.c pjmedia_snd_stream_close.
 15:01:11.459  pjsua_media.c ..failed: No suitable sound capture device

Comment: It is programming question, not App usage question. I'm getting this error after running on Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ipodsound.c - thats not the standard iOS audio driver, are you actually using the pjsip code from pjsip.org?

Comment: No. I am using TabikPhone project and it is giving the above mentioned error.

Comment: From memory the tabik project is very out of date. If possible you should use the stable trunk from pjsip